# Highlight serie hover highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, hover, highlight

Is there a way to highlight the overflown with Highcharts as shown in the screenshot attached line. I tried with the crosshair setting but the legend of the y-axis is not taken into account.

Thank you in advance for your help.

http://cl.ly/image/1E1P0N3E2s26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `renderer.rect()` and update it's position on mouseOver, see: http://jsfiddle.net/NUP9m/4/

Code to add box:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
            load: function () {
                this.highlight = this.renderer.rect(0, -100, 500, 40).attr({
                    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.2)',
                    zIndex: 0
                }).add();
            }
        }
    },
```

To manage box:

```
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        var h = this.series.chart.highlight;

                        if (h) {
                            // h.show();
                            h.attr({
                                y:  this.series.chart.plotTop - this.plotX + this.series.chart.plotHeight - h.height / 2
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        var h = this.series.chart.highlight;

                        if (h) {
                            // h.hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Note, that mouseOut is optional, only required if you want to hide box, when you leave container or point.